# Проблема с mouseup на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент `span` на форме, в `onmousedown` которого производится его удаление и вызов некоего события. В этом событии отправляется Ajax-запрос к серверу.

Проблема, видимо, в том, что пока браузер ждет от сервера ответа, он игнорирует все получаемые события, в результате чего видим следующий эффект. Нажимаем на `span`, он удаляется, но после этого все движения мышкой по странице приводят к выделению текста, пока вновь не нажмем и не отпустим. Видимо, событие `onmouseup` пропускается браузером во время ожидания ответа от сервера и не срабатывает.

Пример, к сожалению, приложить не могу, но думаю, что описал понятно. Как можно с этим бороться?

Comment: `$.ajax({ async: true, ...`

Comment: @Igor ща набегут )))

Comment: @KAGGDesign все приготовил, не пропущу